# complicated update query

Tags: ms-access

.
Hi, I do not know SQL, so I would like a someone to do me a big favor and provide me with the complete SQL to copy and paste into a blank query.

I would like to create an action query, to delete certain text in the field  “USER_1” in my parts table, based on my criteria below:

1: If the field user1 contains text with parenthesis and the first word in the parenthesis
begins with the word "USE" example: "Widget, 2mm x 0.5mm (USE made to
Order, dont backorder)", Then I would like the action query to update the text to  "USER_1" to be "Widget, 2mm x 0.5mm".

1. if the description’s prefix begins with "C/*" or "U/*" or "U/C*" or
   "S/*" or "M/*" or “C/U*”,  then I want the prefix omitted from the description as well. 
   Example: if the description is like "U/Widget, 2mm x 0.5mm”, Then I would like the action query to update the text in
   field "user_1"  to be "Widget, 2mm x 0.5mm".

Some descriptions may contain both of the above criteria, with a prefix and the
Parenthesis. If this is the case, then I want to omit both the prefix and the
parenthesis. Example: If the description is like "C/Widget, 2mm x 0.5mm (USE
Made to order, dont backorder)" then I want field "user_1" to be "Widget, 2mm x 0.5mm”.

I need the criteria not to be case sensitive, so it should delete the text regardless if it is upper or lower case.

thank you very much in advance! Nathaniel

```
SELECT p.ID, p.USER_1
```

FROM SYSADM_PART AS p;

Comment: Sorry, this site is for help with problems, not "do this for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MS Access, which has a query design window which will guide you through creating the SQL you need. That is the strength of Access, you do not need to know SQL to create moderately complex queries. You can also read up on SQL in Access in these three articles:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

You might also like to read about [mid, right, left, instr, instrrev and replace](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/CH010072891.aspx?CTT=97)